# How to check the installed Linux kernel version on Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, dpkg, version

For a DevOPS script, after upgrading a Debian system I need to check the currently latest installed Linux kernel version on Debian, and compare it to the running version (`uname -r`).

What is the simplest way to figure this out?

How do I automatically reboot the system if necessary?

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the question, the currently running kernel can be obtained via:

```
uname -r
```

> The output looks like this:
>
> ```
> 4.19.0-8-amd64
> ```

In contrast, the version of the latest kernel package needs to be taken from the package manager. Assuming an `amd64` architecture and a standard installation, we can check the dependencies of the `linux-image-amd64` meta-package, which always points to the latest kernel package:

```
dpkg-query -f '${Package}: ${Depends}\n' -W linux-image-amd64
```

> The output looks like this:
>
> ```
> linux-image-amd64: linux-image-4.19.0-8-amd64
> ```

To put this into a shell script, two extra steps are needed. First, we should determine the architecture automatically via:

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

> The output looks like this:
>
> ```
> amd64
> ```

Second, we need to strip the `linux-image-` prefix from the kernel package name:

```
echo linux-image-4.19.0-8-amd64 | sed s/^linux-image-//
```

> The output looks like this:
>
> ```
> 4.19.0-8-amd64
> ```

Putting this all together and adding proper shell script quoting, we arrive at:

```
if [ "$(uname -r)" != "$(dpkg-query -f '${Depends}' -W "linux-image-$(dpkg --print-architecture)" | sed s/^linux-image-//)" ]; then
  reboot
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this in a generic way is [explained in this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/699899/90931).

Copy and paste this script, make is executable and run it will give you expected result.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to that related question!