# Verifying the running kernel matches the latest installed kernel in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, software-updates, unattended-upgrades

`unattended-upgrades` in Ubuntu automatically installs security updates including the kernel but does not reboot automatically (and it's OK, I don't need/want automatic reboots).

How can I find out whether `the running kernel = the latest installed kernel`?

I can get the current kernel version by:

```bsh
$ uname -r
5.4.0-104-generic
```

The latest installed kernel can be found out by:

```bsh
$ dpkg -s linux-image-generic | awk '/Version:/{print $2}'
5.4.0.104.108
```

These two don't match. I can use bash sorcery to compare these two strings (and then `.108` needs to go - why?) but I'd prefer to use something standard.

Comment: Would `dpkg-query -l` work?

Comment: If you need auto reboot when needed you can configure it in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`

Comment: I can't autoreboot. We are talking about production servers.

Answer (score 7):

The following is what I use, and should work across different distros.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

HIGHEST_KERNEL=`find /boot/vmlinuz-* | sort -V | tail -n 1 | sed 's|.*vmlinuz-||'`
RUNNING_KERNEL=`uname -r`
echo "Highest Kernel: $HIGHEST_KERNEL | Running Kernel: $RUNNING_KERNEL"
if [ "$HIGHEST_KERNEL" != "$RUNNING_KERNEL" ]; then
  echo "** Reboot Required **"
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

In such situations, on the assumption that the system always boots the latest kernel, I compare the boot time to the kernel image’s timestamp. The simplest way to do that is to use `/proc/1` as a proxy:

```
find /boot -newer /proc/1 -name vmlinuz\*
```

If that lists anything, the system needs to be rebooted (which can be done with an appropriate `-exec`).

If you only use packaged kernels, you can also check for the presence of `/run/reboot-required`; if it exists, a reboot is required. `/run/reboot-required.pkgs` will list the packages which requested a reboot.

You can also use `needrestart` from the eponymous package:

```
needrestart -k
```

Comment: This all looks a little bit finicky, uncertain and fuzzy. In Fedora/RHEL/OpenSuse this can be verified to a letter without any tricks. I wonder why Ubuntu/Debian make it so damn difficult. I really need a simple `if [ $version_installed = $version_running ]; then echo "We are fine"; fi`

Comment: Well, how about `if [ ! -f /run/reboot-required ]; then echo "We are fine"; fi`?

Comment: This file may or may not exist, I may have had a FS malfunction, I may have deleted or added new kernels manually, it's inconsequential. I've found out how to verify this, I'm now penning an answer

Comment: If `/run` malfunctions, you’re in trouble anyway ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu makes it unusually difficult for some reasons and the answer below applies only (!) to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and may or may not work for other releases.

So, like I mentioned in the question you can get the latest installed kernel by:

```
$ version_installed=`dpkg -s linux-image-generic | awk '/Version:/{print $2}'`
$ echo "$version_installed"
5.4.0.104.108
```

The last number, `#108`, doesn't seem relevant, so let's trim it:

```bsh
$ version_installed=`dpkg -s linux-image-generic | awk '/Version:/{print $2}'` | awk -F . '{print $1"."$2"."$3"."$4}'` # this can be improved but I'm too lazy
$ echo "$version_installed"
5.4.0.104
```

`uname -r` gives us the version with some unnecessary bits: `5.4.0-104-generic`. Let's fix it:

```bsh
$ version_running=`uname -r | sed 's/-generic//;s/-/\./;` # could be simplified as well
$ echo "$version_running"
5.4.0.104
```

Now we can

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

version_installed=`dpkg -s linux-image-generic | awk '/Version:/{print $2}' | awk -F . '{print $1"."$2"."$3"."$4}'`
version_running=`uname -r | sed 's/-generic//;s/-/\./'`

if [ "$version_installed"  = "$version_running" ]; then
    echo "All Good"
else
    echo "Life is a misery"
fi
```